# Is a container sure to be a range conceptually?

Tags: c++, standards, language-design, range-v3, c++-experimental

From the documentation of [ranges-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html#range-views):

> `view::all`
>
> Return a range containing all the elements in the source.
>   Useful for converting containers to ranges.

What makes me confused are:

1. Under what scenarios are `view::all` used?
2. Are standard containers (`std::vector`, `std::list`, etc.) not
   ranges conceptually?

For example:

```
auto coll = std::vector{ 1, 2, 2, 3 };  
view::all(coll) | view::unique; // version 1
coll | view::unique; // version 2
```

**Is there any difference between `version 1` and `version 2`?**

Comment: Range is not a concept.  It is a class template.

Comment: No, Range is a concept.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Egad, that part of the documentation hasn't been updated since range-v3 switched terminology. Yes, a container is a Range (it has `begin()` and `end()` that return an iterator/sentinel pair). It is not a View (a Range with O(1) copy/move). So, the documentation for `view::all` should read:

> `view::all`
>
> Return a View containing all the elements in the source. Useful for converting containers to Views.

To answer your second question, no there is no difference between version 1 and version 2 in your code.

Comment: Follow up question: So the main purpose of `views::all` is **to convert** Ranges (not just containers) to Views, in order to (maybe) perform O(1) operations? If not, what's a case where `views::all` actually wraps a non-trivial range?

Comment: Yes, the purpose of `views::all` is to convert a range to a view so it can be manipulated in O(1).

Comment: Could the name may as well be sth like, `views::to_view`?